# Can't pull a string for apex:image

Tags: string, image-formula

My client has a 'technical document' which shows you some data about their product, I created a button that gather these information and creates a page and it's all working fine. But depending on what type of product is, the document brings you a symbol (there's 7 of them). I created an url for each of them to help me while I'm coding, with this pattern: /resource/Symbology_X, so if you select A, it'll bring you /resource/Symbology_A and so on...

So, the controller is like this (working fine):

```
if(product.lsSymbol__c == 'A'){
         fieldSymbol = '/resource/Simbology_A';
        }
        else if (product.lsSymbol__c == 'B'){
         fieldSymbol = '/resource/Simbology_B';
        }
        else if (product.lsSymbol__c == 'C'){
         fieldSymbol = '/resource/Simbology_C';
        }
        else if (product.lsSymbol__c == 'D'){
         fieldSymbol = '/resource/Simbology_D';
        }
        else if (product.lsSymbol__c == 'E'){
         fieldSymbol = '/resource/Simbology_E';
        }
        else if (product.lsSymbol__c == 'F'){
         fieldSymbol  = '/resource/Simbology_F';
        }
        else if (product.lsSymbol__c == 'G'){
         fieldSymbol = '/resource/Simbology_G';
        }
```

**The problem is here (.page)**

If I test like this, it works:

```
<p style="margin-top: -7px;" class="bold">{!title[9]} </p>

<apex:image url = "/resource/Simbology_A" style="width:100%;margin-top:-5px;"/>
```

But it needs to change the symbol depending on which type of product is, so if change "/resource/Simbology_A" to "{!fieldSymbol}", it gives me this error:

***Open quote is expected for attribute "url" associated with an  element type  "apex:image".***

Answer (score 0):

Don't put spaces between the attribute, equals sign, and value:

```
<apex:image url="{!fieldSymbol}" ...
```

While this is sometimes allowed, it's a bad habit to get in.